# Configuring Apache drill for Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra, apache-drill

I am trying to configure Cassandra with Drill. I used the same approach given on the link: https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-the-web-ui/.

I used the following code for New Storage Plugin:

```
 {
  "type": "cassandra",
  "hosts": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ],
  "port": 9042,
  "username": "<username>",
  "password": "<password>",
  "enabled": false
}
```

[I have attached the Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX3LA.png)

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Please retry: Error (invalid JSON mapping)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the code :

1. Git: https://github.com/yssharma/drill/tree/cassandra-storage
2. Patch: https://gist.github.com/yssharma/2581ae8a97c559b2677f

**1. Get Drill: Lets get the Drill source**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/drill.git
```

**2. Get Cassandra Storage patch/Download the Patch file from:**

```
https://reviews.apache.org/r/29816/diff/raw/
```

**3. Apply the patch on top of Drill**
$ cd drill
$ git apply --check ~/Downloads/DRILL-92-CassandraStorage.patch
$ git apply ~/Downloads/DRILL-92-CassandraStorage.patch

**4. Build Drill with Cassandra Storage & export distribution to /opt/drill**

```
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ mkdir /opt/drill
$ tar xvzf distribution/target/*.tar.gz --strip=1 -C /opt/drill
```

**5. Start Sqlline.**
That it we have finished with the Drill build and installation – and its time we can start using Drill.

```
$ cd /opt/drill
$ bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local -n admin -p admin
Drill-Sqlline
```

Hit ‘show schemas‘ to view existing schemas.

Drill-Sqlline-schemas

**6. Drill Web interface**
You should be able to see the Drill web interface on localhost:8047, or whatever your host/port is.

**Use this as your config:**

```
 {
      "type": "cassandra",
      "config": {
        "cassandra.hosts": [
          "127.0.0.1",
          "127.0.0.2"
        ],
        "cassandra.port": 9042
      },
      "enabled": true
    }
```

Also, if this doesnt work, know that they are working on a plugin for it now: `https://github.com/apache/drill/pull/1960`

Comment: Adding some commentary will go a long way to explain why this solves the OP's question. Just a code dump alone is not that helpful.

Comment: Sure, but all it seemed like he was missing the right json config based on his ask. Either way, i left something in full detail.

Comment: The whole point of SO is not answering one person's question, but to have a repository of questions-answers for anybody that might be facing similar problems in the future. The extra commentary will serve those future visitors. Hence the entire voting system. See the [tour] for more info.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense - thanks for explaining that because that is useful for answering future questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an update here as well.  We're doing some serious refactoring of the how Drill works with storage plugins. Specifically, we're working to incorporate the Calcite Adapter[1](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html) for Cassandra.  The reason for this is that the hard part of storage plugins isn't the connection, it's the optimizations.  Calcite already does query planning for Drill and already implemented a bunch of these adapters which means that the work of figuring out all the optimizations (AKA pushdowns) is largely done.

In the case of Cassandra/Scylla, this is particularly important because some filters should be pushed down to Cassandra, and some should absolutely not be pushed down.  The adapters also include aggregate pushdowns--something which no Drill plugins currently do.  Again the point of this is that once we commit this, the connector should work VERY will with Cassandra/Scylla.  We have one for ElasticSearch that is very near completion and once that's done the Cassandra plugin is next.  If you have any suggestions/comments or other feedback, please post on the pull request linked above.

** UPDATE 11 April 2021: Cassandra/Scylla Plugin Now Merged in Drill 1.19.0-SNAPSHOT **